# How to make vim always show the encoding of current opened file?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to configure vim to do this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set your GUI title, statusline, or ruler to show the information.  See:

```
:help 'statusline'
:help status-line
:help 'laststatus'
:help 'rulerformat'
:help 'titlestring'
```

For example, you could do:

```
:set laststatus=2 statusline=%f\ %m\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}
```